# GetComponentsInChildren<GameObject>() raises error

Tags: unity, c#

I have a gameobject to which a script is attached.

In this script I have the following code:

```
    foreach (GameObject g in this.GetComponentsInChildren<GameObject>())
    {
        BagItem nBagItemScript = g.GetComponent<BagItem>();
        if (nBagItemScript != null)
        {
            Bounds nBounds = Helpers.BoundsFromGO(g);

            Vector3 nPos = new Vector3((nBounds.size.x / 2) - nBounds.center.x, mapHeight - (nBounds.size.y / 2) - nBounds.center.y, -0.01f);
            g.transform.localPosition = nPos;

        }
    }
```

I thought this code was fail-safe, but Unity outputs the following error message:

ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'GameObject' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.
UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren[GameObject] (Boolean includeInactive) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/GameObject.bindings.cs:133)
UnityEngine.Component.GetComponentsInChildren[GameObject] (Boolean includeInactive) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Component.bindings.cs:88)
UnityEngine.Component.GetComponentsInChildren[GameObject] () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Component.bindings.cs:98)
Bag.pUpdatePositions () (at Assets/Bag.cs:173)
Bag.Update () (at Assets/Bag.cs:107)

Can somebody tell me which error Unity / C# is choking on here?

Is the error really in this line

```
foreach (GameObject g in this.GetComponentsInChildren<GameObject>())
```

... or perhaps somewhere else?

Thank you very much!

Comment: [It's been explained to you previously](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/171565/39518) that you can't `GetComponentsInChildren<GameObject>()` because `GameObject` is not a `Component`. If you want to iterate over child objects, use the `Transform` since it owns the transformation hierarchy.

Comment: In my answer on DMGregorys linked question was what I was referring to with the possible null reference & derive from gameobject errors. Just use the Transform. the transform can then reference the childrens game objects with no troubles or errors. You can still store your Gameobject variable as a Gameobject also in case that was of concern or a possible reason why you would want to avoid using the transform in the first place. hope that helps.